# Vuejs2 - Not able to install the datepicker

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

In my vuejs project I want to install the "datepicker". I have executed this

```
npm install vue2-datepicker --save
```

But it's not installed properly and it's throwing error such as ,

> npm ERR! path
>   D:\DEV\spring-boot-vuejs\frontend\node_modules\vue2-datepicker npm
>   ERR! code ENOENT npm ERR! errno -4058 npm ERR! syscall rename npm ERR!
>   enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename
>   'D:\DEV\spring-boot-vuejs\frontend\node_modules\vue2-datepicker' ->
>   'D:\DEV\spring-boot-vuejs\frontend\node_modules.vue2-datepicker.DELETE'
>   npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
>   npm ERR! enoent

How to get rid of this error and how to install the datepicker successfully?

Comment: Try deleting your `node_modules` folder and running `npm install` again

Comment: @Phiter Thanks it works!. I have deleted the node-modules folder and re-install. After I have run this script "npm install vue2-datepicker --save" and then it works. But what is the reason for this ??

Comment: Some times the installed files can glitch. ENOENT means node couldn't find a certain file, that's why reinstalling everything could fix it.

Comment: Oh, ok. Thanks! @Phiter

Comment: yeah particularly on windows. it likes to lock folders. the only way is to delete the node_modules folder and npm install again.

Comment: stop the service and run 'npm run dev'